# Form submission to create multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create multiple objects by submitting a form with one single textarea input.

I envision:
- each line, a new object
- attributes are separated by commas

E.g. for a `User` model with the attributes: `name`, `email`, `activated`

```
Larry Page, larry@google.com, false
Jeff Bezos, jeff@amazon.com, true
Mark Zuckerburg, mark@fb.com, false
```

How would I, in the controller, convert the form submission to one array for each "object" (such that I then can iterate over them and perform creation)?

Comment: You can't do that in a pretty form, you have to construct your array in the controller

Comment: ahhh okei, sorry for missunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you could turn your user input into an array supposing that each line is separated by a newline character:

```
textfield_value = "Larry Page, larry@google.com, false\nJeff Bezos, jeff@amazon.com, true\nMark Zuckerburg, mark@fb.com, false"

textfield_value.each_line do |d|
  row = d.split(",")
  MyModel.create(name: row[0], email: row[1], activated: row[2]
end
```

This can be refactored further. Just giving you an idea.